# Trouble getting download Url of uploaded file in Android Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, download, firebase-storage

I my trying to upload a profile picture to Firebase storage and then save it's download URL to database. The uploading works perfect but I'm facing problems with the download URL. I've tried almost everything on Stack Overflow. I'm sharing the relevant code.

```
private String user_Name, user_Email, user_Password, user_Age, user_Phone, imageUri;
Uri imagePath;
```

Selecting image

```
userProfilePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");                                                              //Specify the type of intent
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);                                            //What action needs to be performed.
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), 
            }
        });

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {           //Here we get the result from startActivityForResult().
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data.getData() != null){
            imagePath = data.getData();                                                                 //data.getData() holds the path of the file.
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imagePath);     //this converts the Uri to an image.
                userProfilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imageTrue = 1;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

uploading data

```
 private void sendUserData (){
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users").child(firebaseAuth.getUid());
        final StorageReference imageReference = storageReference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Images").child("Profile Pic");
                                                    //Here the root storage reference of our app storage is is "storageReference".
                                                    //.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()) creates a folder for every user. .child("images")
                                                    //creates another subfolder Images and the last child() function
                                                    //.child("Profile Pic") always gives the name of the file.
                                                    //User id/Images/profile_pic.png
                                                    //We can follow the same process for all other file types.

        if(imageTrue==1){
            UploadTask uploadTask = imageReference.putFile(imagePath);     //Now we need to upload the file.
            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Upload Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    imageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            Uri downloadUri = uri;
                            imageUri = downloadUri.toString();

                        }
                    });
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Uploaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }


        UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile(user_Name, user_Age, user_Email, user_Phone, imageUri);
        myRef.setValue(userProfile);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Data Sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right. You  just need to make some correction inside your code in **sendUserData()** function. You will get your imageUrl inside `onSuccess` of your **UploadTask**

```
  DatabaseReference myRef;

     private void sendUserData (){
            FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users").child(firebaseAuth.getUid());
            final StorageReference imageReference = storageReference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Images").child("Profile Pic");
                                                        //Here the root storage reference of our app storage is is "storageReference".
                                                        //.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()) creates a folder for every user. .child("images")
                                                        //creates another subfolder Images and the last child() function
                                                        //.child("Profile Pic") always gives the name of the file.
                                                        //User id/Images/profile_pic.png
                                                        //We can follow the same process for all other file types.

            if(imageTrue==1){
                UploadTask uploadTask = imageReference.putFile(imagePath);     //Now we need to upload the file.
                uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Upload Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        imageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                Uri downloadUri = uri;
                                imageUri = downloadUri.toString();
                                saveUserDetails(imageUri); // Image uploaded
                            }
                        });
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Uploaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            }else{
                saveUserDetails(""); // Image not uploaded
            }
    }
```

Common function for `saveUserDetails`:

```
   public void saveUserDetails(String imageUri){

           UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile(user_Name, user_Age, user_Email, user_Phone, imageUri);
                myRef.setValue(userProfile);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Data Sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
```

Comment: Dear Bhoomika thanks for the prompt reply. I have tried the same thing except the saveUserDetails function. Further the storage reference "myRef" is in sendUserData function which can't be accessed in sendUserDetails.

Comment: make that global. Or you should also pass that to saveUserDetails.

Comment: Wow. It works. If possible, can you tell what was wrong with my code. I mean why the uploading wouldn't work directly from sendUserData?

Comment: Great. Glad that it helps you.

Comment: Its because your UploadTask is working in background and you put your myRef.serValue Code outside of that. So both are exwcuting at same time. so You didn't get imgUrl

Comment: @FahadAli: the download URL is retrieved asynchronously from Firebase. By the time the `new UserProfile(user_Name, user_Age, user_Email, user_Phone, imageUri)` ran in your original, code, the `onSuccess` that gets the download URL hadn't run yet. All code that requires the download URL must be inside the `onSuccess` handler for `getDownloadUrl`, or be called from within there.

Comment: Can you accept this answer, so other can also get guidance from this. Thanks

Comment: @FahadAli Please accept & upvote this answer. So it may also helps others in future :)

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel Thanks for the solution and explanation. I've voted and accepted the answer.

Comment: @FahadAli glad that this helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

according to [Firebase official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files)  you can get download URl using `UploadTask` on `addOnCompleteListener` method.

```
UploadTask uploadTask =null;
final StorageReference ref = storageReference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Images").child("Profile Pic").child(imagePath);
uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw task.getException();
        }

        // Continue with the task to get the download URL
        return ref.getDownloadUrl();
    }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
          saveUserDetails(uri);
        } else {
            // Handle failures
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

another alternative way , after uploading image successfully query and get your image url by using get downloadUrl.hope this may helps you!

```
private void getImageUrl(){
     storageReference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Images").child("Profile Pic").child(imagePath).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                saveUserDetails(uri);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle any errors
            }
        });

}
```